# How can I make clear a statement is a hyperbole or generalization?

Tags: phrase-request

Over on Meta Stack Overflow I wrote [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/305956/578411) that starts with the following statement:

> we shouldn't care about attitudes of users.

That is not a statement which is true for me or how readers should understand it.

I think I want to make clear that the statement is an [hyperbole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbole).

In my first iteration I wrote:

> In an over general way stated: we shouldn't care about attitudes of users.

which was declared as [*quite awkward*](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/25676220#25676220)

Other suggestions were:

> In an overly general way

In the end I decided on

> Generally (meant as an hyperbole)

but that still feels as not the correct way to state that.

How can I correctly convey in a single, short sentence that my first statement is a broad generalization/hyperbole and not (necessarily) my own opinion?

Comment: "If I dare to exaggerate, ..."

Comment: @Rene I would point out that it's an hyperbole in some kinda footnote. Did you consider doing it that way? It doesn't need to be that obvious, nor that straightforward. For instance, take a look at what I did [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/design-request-can-i-please-have-the-visited-questions-in-a-different-color).

Comment: Ordinarily, I would not understand *hyperbole* to include contexts involving nothing more than *[over-] generalization.*

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M: I think ***an** hyperbole* is a [dated Victorian usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+hyperbole%2Can+hyperbole&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20hyperbole%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20hyperbole%3B%2Cc0). Everyone enunciates the /h/ today - consequently, *nearly* everyone writes ***a** hyperbole*.

Comment: @Fumble thanks for the tip. Rene, I again think you should do this in a footnote. The effect and the amusement that your statement brings is ruined by adding "this is meant to be 'hyperbole'" in the same sentence in an appositive.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for strategic writing advice.

Comment: Terms like *hyperbole* or *exaggeration* or *joke* just slow things down. They tell the reader what you ***don't*** mean&mdash;at the very point where it's important to set up what you ***do*** mean. If I were going to use the *don't care* piece I would open something like this: *If a post doesn't cross the line into misbehavior we shouldn't care about the poster's underlying attitude.*  That immediately tells your readers the domain within which your provocative statement applies, and reassures them that you recognize a domain within which it does not.

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M: I think it might be a bit "patronising" to actually add a footnote *I deliberately overstated this for the sake of [amusing/shocking] effect*. If it really was important to make sure no readers were misled into thinking the words were intended *literally*, perhaps they could be followed within the text by something like the bracketed disclaimer **(admittedly, something of an overstatement)**. But that's all "writing advice".

Comment: @StoneyB I didn't realize I was ready for strategic writing advice. I like your suggestion though, tnx for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pose a rhetorical question that states an extreme position:

**Should we give a damn what users think?**

And then answer your question however you see fit:

**No, we shouldn't.

Of course we should.**